# FFmpeg unable to find a suitable output format when run from script

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm trying to write bash script, which I can use to start encode of my video for web player, and also log to file when it started / finished.

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
>/var/www/stat/encode.txt
echo "on $(date +%s)" > /var/www/stat/encode.txt
ffmpeg -i 'suzumiya.mkv' -preset slow -crf 18 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -movflags faststart -tune animation -profile:v baseline -vf "ass=suzumiya.ass" 'suzu.mp4'
echo "off $(date +%s)" > /var/www/stat/encode.txt
```

When I run it, it tells me:

```
'NULL @ 0x20ad4c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'suzu.mp4
: Invalid argument
```

When I just copypaste the ffmpeg code to console, it works well, no error. Where can be problem?

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version N-63938-g684a915 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2014 18:07:52 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-gray --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-bzlib --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-openal --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'suzumiya.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya: Special Ending
    encoder         : libebml v0.7.7 + libmatroska v0.8.0
    creation_time   : 2007-05-09 12:50:35
  Duration: 00:01:11.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3580 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 704x480, SAR 229:189 DAR 5038:2835, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya: Special Ending
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : 2ch Vorbis
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ssa (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Styled ASS
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ssa
    Metadata:
      title           : Styled ASS (Simple)
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Plain SRT
    Stream #0:5: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : GosmickSansBold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:6: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : epmgobld_ending.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
'NULL @ 0x20ad4c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'suzu.mp4
: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please note that you have to indent code by 4 spaces (use the code button in our editor and check the preview). For your issue: Are you absolutely sure the script is *exactly* as you posted here? Nothing else apart from the quotes? Try replacing single with double quotes. It shouldn't really matter but you might have some special character there.

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but try adding `-f mp4` before the output filename.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the "coding" of the scriptfile is wrong.
I had the same problem when I made the scriptfile on a windows machine and ran it on a linux machine. 
Especially how the linebreaks are coded. Should be **(LF)** on linux and not (CR LF) as my windows machine wrote it. 
In Notepad++ on windows you can easily change this or just make a new file on the linuxmachine and copy-paste the code there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168340)